# Ошибка в c++ коде - сбивается ссылка

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов

Здравствуйте! У меня не работает код:

```
template<class T>Cl<T>& Cl<T>::operator + (Cl<T>& cl) {
  Cl<T> newCl((this->size)+(cl.size));
  //
  return newCl;
}

template<class T>Cl<T>& Cl<T>::operator = (Cl<T>& cl) {
  //
  return *this;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  //
  Cl<int>cl1(10);
  //
  Cl<int>cl2(10);
  //
  cl1 = (cl1 + cl2);
  //
}
```

При заходе в присваивание ссылка cl сбивается на непонятно что, в частности, size становится отрицательным и при попытке создать массив происходит bad_alloc.

Answer (score 2):

Классика - возврат ссылки на локальный (то бишь удаленный после выхода из функции) объект.

```
template<class T>
Cl<T> Cl<T>::operator + (const Cl<T>& cl) const {
    Cl<T> newCl((this->size)+(cl.size));
    //
    return newCl;
}
```

Так вот оно как-то лучше будет...

И да - вот тут тоже измените:

```
template<class T>Cl<T>& Cl<T>::operator = (const Cl<T>& cl) {
  //
  return *this;
}
```

а то не сработает при присваивании rvalue.

Comment: Спасибо. Всё сработало.

Comment: Ну, если решение устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, отметив решение как принятое...

Comment: и в `operator +` пару раз `const` добавить не мешало бы...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вы правы, подправляю.